# Strikeout text in Windows phone 7

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, text-formatting

Is there a way to strikeout text in windows phone 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/19749.aspx), someone also posted a solution there.

Comment: Invalid attribute value Strikethrough for property TextDecorations. [Line: 33 Position: 28]

Comment: Code needs a bit more refining but it does it job. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to do this.
The only alternative is to draw a line in the same position as the text yourself.

Answer (score 2):

A little simple example:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some text" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FF949494" >
        </Border>
        </Grid>
```