# Windows Phone 8 Strikethrough

Tags: windows-phone-8, textblock, strikethrough

I'm developing a windows phone 8 application.
I've got a textblock with a price in it. 
Only thing I want to do is a line through the textblock.

I've tried to use the Line function but that one doesn't work because the textblock has a variable length. 
Does anyone know how I can make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me thanks to [Chkon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188376/chkon) for giving me the answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059254/strikeout-text-in-windows-phone-7):

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Some text" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FF949494" >
        </Border>
</Grid>
```